# Google app engine form not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm having troubles with Google App Engine. It is all set up (and working hour before), when I reconnected the Engine the form simply stop working, when I hit submit, the page goes to the server's page and nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost:9080/sub" method="post">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
import webapp2
class SubscribeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        email = self.request.get("email")
        if email == '':
            self.response.out.write("no email")
        self.response.out.write(email)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/sub', SubscribeHandler)], debug=True)
```

Comment: What does the log say? Try and put in debug statements.

Comment: It was a import error: "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb". I did not know about the log, from today I will use it.

Comment: Are you sure you have MySQLdb declared in your app's [libraries section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Configuring_libraries)?

Comment: I fix it. The lib was not installed